# Why is my urllib.quote in python encoding from Win-1252 instead of UTF-8 for CSV file?

Tags: python, csv, encoding, utf-8, urllib

I've been trying to URL Encode my inputs to get them ready for an API request and the urllib.quote works great with a string and encodes it the way it's supposed to from utf-8, but when it's from a csv file, it encodes it in a way that the API request does not recognize.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import urllib
r = "Handøl Sweden"
print urllib.quote(r)
```

This returns the correct format:

```
Hand%C3%B8l%20Sweden
```

Whereas:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import urllib
import csv

CityList = []

with open ('SiteValidate4.csv','rb') as csvfile:
    CityData = csv.reader(csvfile)
    for row in CityData:
        CityList.append(row[12])
        r = row[12]
print r
print urllib.quote(r)
```

This returns:

```
Handøl Sweden
Hand%F8l%20Sweden
```

Are there any fixes to encode the input from the .csv file to the correct format?

Comment: Did you try `r = row[12].decode("utf8")`?

Comment: @cdonts: the data is encoded to CP1252, so that'll fail. And `urllib.quote()` needs a *bytestring*, so you need to *re-encode*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your CSV file is encoded to CP-1252, you'd have to re-code that to UTF-8:

```
r = r.decode('cp1252').encode('utf8')
```

Your plain Python code was using UTF-8 *bytes*; provided your code editor indeed saved the data as UTF-8 as your `coding: utf-8` header implies.

Just putting a [PEP 263](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263/) header in your Python source file doesn't magically make all data you read from a file UTF-8 data too; it'll still need to be decoded with the correct codec *for that file*.

Comment: Is there a way to specify the character set for the csv reader so bytes are properly decoded to characters per UTF-8?

Comment: @chrislott: no, there isn't, not in Python 2. You *have* to decode after parsing as CSV.

Comment: @chrislott: see the [*Examples* section](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#examples) of the `csv` module documentation; there's code there to *recode* Unicode input so other codecs can be handled more transparently.

Comment: @chrislott You can, using the [`io.open`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/io.html#io.open) function which lets you specify an `encoding` argument.

Comment: @cdonts: but the `csv` module cannot handle Unicode input. You have to encode the lines, then decode after parsing. *The csv module doesn’t directly support reading and writing Unicode, but it is 8-bit-clean save for some problems with ASCII NUL characters. So you can write functions or classes that handle the encoding and decoding for you as long as you avoid encodings like UTF-16 that use NULs. UTF-8 is recommended.*

Comment: @MartijnPieters Thanks, I thought the `csv` module was able to handle unicode.

Comment: @cdonts in Python 2 they advise you to open the file in binary mode - that doesn't sound unicode-friendly to me.